# How to pivot after grouping in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select day,type,sum(type)
from table1
group by 1,2
```

It returned something like this

```
day            type  count(type)
2021-04-13      a       10
2021-04-13      b       5 
2021-04-14      c       2
```

but my desired result is as follows
I would like to pivot them . how can I transform them?

```
    2021-04-13   2021-04-14  
a      10           0           
      
b       5           0          
 
c       0           2
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the type of `type` column?

Comment: their type is string.. I stacked to pivot them . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Presumably, you intend:

```
select day,
       count(*) filter (where date = '2021-04-13') as cnt_20210413,
       count(*) filter (where date = '2021-04-14') as cnt_20210414
from table1
group by day;
```

Note that your query has `sum(type)`, but `type` is then shown with the values that are non-numeric strings.  Hence, confusion.  I am guessing you really intend `count()` and not `sum()`.

Comment: Thank you for comment , and I guess whether can I get like 1week, 7days from now. like`date BETWEEN getdate()-7 AND getdate() ` . the filter still work in these situation.. ?